# cakephp SQL Server error

Tags: cakephp, sql-server-2000

I have the following database connection configuration:

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv.DboSqlsrv',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'sa',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'prospect',
    'port' => NULL,

    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

I use the [DboSqlsrv plugin](https://github.com/revathskumar/CakePHP-sqlsrv-driver). When I run my application, I receive an error:

> error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sys.synonyms'. [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]
>
> Query: select SUBSTRING(base_object_name,2,LEN(base_object_name)-2) as
>   object,name as TABLE_NAME from sys.synonyms
>
> Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   [APP\plugins\sqlsrv\models\datasources\dbo\dbo_sqlsrv.php, line 253]
>
> Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
>   by (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prospect\cake\libs\debugger.php:683)
>   [CORE\cake\libs\controller\components\request_handler.php, line 759]

But when I refresh the page, the error is gone. I can login, but when I refresh the page the error is shown again.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

You are giving wrong value for driver i guess....try this way instead....let me know your configuration settings for a better answer.

```
var $default = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'prospect',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

Hope this wil lelp you.